# Is there a way to save tkinter canvas to a pdf?

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, pdf-generation, tkinter-canvas

I have been thinking on how to save my tkinter canvas to pdf but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I don't know where to start from as at now. I have searched for how to do such a thing on google and youtube yet I'm not getting any.

The frequent ones on youtube is creating a text box in a canvas and futhering saving it as a pdf by creating cells.

But with mine I am expecting my canvas to display an information from series of calculations at the back end code. and not necessarily a text.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried. Many of the comments left on your [previous version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74517010/how-to-convert-my-tkinter-window-to-a-pdf-file) still apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
# Geometric figures

from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
w, h = A4

c = canvas.Canvas("figuras.pdf", pagesize=A4)

c.drawString(30, h - 50, "Line")
x = 120
y = h - 45
c.line(x, y, x + 100, y)

c.drawString(30, h - 100, "Rectangle")
c.rect(x, h - 120, 100, 50)

c.drawString(30, h - 170, "Circle")
c.circle(170, h - 165, 20)

c.drawString(30, h - 240, "Ellipse")
c.ellipse(x, y - 170, x + 100, y - 220)

c.showPage()
c.save()
```